# passing nic to guest in qemu using iommu & vfio

Tags: linux-networking, qemu

I bought a 4-port network adapter PCIe card (Intel E1G44HT 10/100/1000Mbps PCI-Express 2.0 Server Adapter I340-T4)

I am trying to install it in my hpZ600 workstation and pass it through to my guest VM

I am running Artix Linux but am mostly following directions for Arch Linux.

The issue is I am unable to pass the card to my VM.

Here is what I've done so far:

First I update my default/grub

```sh
$ sudo -E nvim /etc/default/grub
```

```sh
...
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt vfio-pci.ids=8086:150e"
...
```

Then I remake my grub config

```sh
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

I reboot and make sure things are working

```sh
sudo reboot -h now
```

I check the output of dmesg

```sh
sudo dmesg | grep -i -e DMAR -e IOMMU
```

```sh
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=095a0572-cdd9-402c-80b7-425724b3cf65 rw loglevel=3 quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt vfio-pci.ids=8086:150e
[    0.013145] ACPI: DMAR 0x00000000DEFB8F83 000170 (v01 HPQOEM TYLSBURG 00000001      00000000)
[    0.013171] ACPI: Reserving DMAR table memory at [mem 0xdefb8f83-0xdefb90f2]
[    0.064149] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=095a0572-cdd9-402c-80b7-425724b3cf65 rw loglevel=3 quiet intel_iommu=on iommu=pt vfio-pci.ids=8086:150e
[    0.064257] DMAR: IOMMU enabled
[    0.064301] Unknown kernel command line parameters "BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux intel_iommu=on", will be passed to user space.
[    0.166858] DMAR-IR: This system BIOS has enabled interrupt remapping
[    0.455454] iommu: Default domain type: Passthrough (set via kernel command line)
[    0.485787] DMAR: Host address width 40
[    0.485788] DMAR: DRHD base: 0x000000fed90000 flags: 0x1
[    0.485799] DMAR: dmar0: reg_base_addr fed90000 ver 1:0 cap c90780106f0462 ecap f02076
[    0.485802] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd0000 end: 0x000000defd0fff
[    0.485804] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd1000 end: 0x000000defd1fff
[    0.485805] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd2000 end: 0x000000defd2fff
[    0.485807] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd3000 end: 0x000000defd3fff
[    0.485808] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd4000 end: 0x000000defd4fff
[    0.485809] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd5000 end: 0x000000defd5fff
[    0.485811] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd6000 end: 0x000000defd6fff
[    0.485812] DMAR: RMRR base: 0x000000defd7000 end: 0x000000defd7fff
[    0.485813] DMAR: ATSR flags: 0x0
[    0.485838] DMAR: No SATC found
[    0.485852] DMAR: dmar0: Using Queued invalidation
[    0.485953] pci 0000:00:00.0: Adding to iommu group 0
[    0.485973] pci 0000:00:01.0: Adding to iommu group 1
[    0.485990] pci 0000:00:03.0: Adding to iommu group 2
[    0.486007] pci 0000:00:07.0: Adding to iommu group 3
[    0.486043] pci 0000:00:10.0: Adding to iommu group 4
[    0.486061] pci 0000:00:10.1: Adding to iommu group 4
[    0.486096] pci 0000:00:11.0: Adding to iommu group 5
[    0.486112] pci 0000:00:11.1: Adding to iommu group 5
[    0.486130] pci 0000:00:14.0: Adding to iommu group 6
[    0.486148] pci 0000:00:14.1: Adding to iommu group 7
[    0.486167] pci 0000:00:14.2: Adding to iommu group 8
[    0.486194] pci 0000:00:15.0: Adding to iommu group 9
[    0.486248] pci 0000:00:1a.0: Adding to iommu group 10
[    0.486265] pci 0000:00:1a.1: Adding to iommu group 10
[    0.486282] pci 0000:00:1a.2: Adding to iommu group 10
[    0.486300] pci 0000:00:1a.7: Adding to iommu group 10
[    0.486317] pci 0000:00:1b.0: Adding to iommu group 11
[    0.486353] pci 0000:00:1c.0: Adding to iommu group 12
[    0.486371] pci 0000:00:1c.5: Adding to iommu group 12
[    0.486425] pci 0000:00:1d.0: Adding to iommu group 13
[    0.486444] pci 0000:00:1d.1: Adding to iommu group 13
[    0.486462] pci 0000:00:1d.2: Adding to iommu group 13
[    0.486479] pci 0000:00:1d.7: Adding to iommu group 13
[    0.486496] pci 0000:00:1e.0: Adding to iommu group 14
[    0.486531] pci 0000:00:1f.0: Adding to iommu group 15
[    0.486551] pci 0000:00:1f.2: Adding to iommu group 15
[    0.486572] pci 0000:03:00.0: Adding to iommu group 16
[    0.486591] pci 0000:03:00.1: Adding to iommu group 17
[    0.486612] pci 0000:03:00.2: Adding to iommu group 18
[    0.486630] pci 0000:03:00.3: Adding to iommu group 19
[    0.486652] pci 0000:0f:00.0: Adding to iommu group 20
[    0.486658] pci 0000:01:00.0: Adding to iommu group 12
[    0.486693] pci 0000:3f:00.0: Adding to iommu group 21
[    0.486713] pci 0000:3f:00.1: Adding to iommu group 21
[    0.486767] pci 0000:3f:02.0: Adding to iommu group 22
[    0.486787] pci 0000:3f:02.1: Adding to iommu group 22
[    0.486806] pci 0000:3f:02.4: Adding to iommu group 22
[    0.486825] pci 0000:3f:02.5: Adding to iommu group 22
[    0.486878] pci 0000:3f:03.0: Adding to iommu group 23
[    0.486897] pci 0000:3f:03.1: Adding to iommu group 23
[    0.486916] pci 0000:3f:03.2: Adding to iommu group 23
[    0.486935] pci 0000:3f:03.4: Adding to iommu group 23
[    0.486989] pci 0000:3f:04.0: Adding to iommu group 24
[    0.487009] pci 0000:3f:04.1: Adding to iommu group 24
[    0.487028] pci 0000:3f:04.2: Adding to iommu group 24
[    0.487047] pci 0000:3f:04.3: Adding to iommu group 24
[    0.487100] pci 0000:3f:05.0: Adding to iommu group 25
[    0.487120] pci 0000:3f:05.1: Adding to iommu group 25
[    0.487143] pci 0000:3f:05.2: Adding to iommu group 25
[    0.487163] pci 0000:3f:05.3: Adding to iommu group 25
[    0.487216] pci 0000:3f:06.0: Adding to iommu group 26
[    0.487236] pci 0000:3f:06.1: Adding to iommu group 26
[    0.487276] pci 0000:3f:06.2: Adding to iommu group 26
[    0.487298] pci 0000:3f:06.3: Adding to iommu group 26
[    0.487335] pci 0000:3e:00.0: Adding to iommu group 27
[    0.487356] pci 0000:3e:00.1: Adding to iommu group 27
[    0.487408] pci 0000:3e:02.0: Adding to iommu group 28
[    0.487429] pci 0000:3e:02.1: Adding to iommu group 28
[    0.487451] pci 0000:3e:02.4: Adding to iommu group 28
[    0.487472] pci 0000:3e:02.5: Adding to iommu group 28
[    0.487527] pci 0000:3e:03.0: Adding to iommu group 29
[    0.487549] pci 0000:3e:03.1: Adding to iommu group 29
[    0.487571] pci 0000:3e:03.2: Adding to iommu group 29
[    0.487593] pci 0000:3e:03.4: Adding to iommu group 29
[    0.487647] pci 0000:3e:04.0: Adding to iommu group 30
[    0.487669] pci 0000:3e:04.1: Adding to iommu group 30
[    0.487692] pci 0000:3e:04.2: Adding to iommu group 30
[    0.487716] pci 0000:3e:04.3: Adding to iommu group 30
[    0.487770] pci 0000:3e:05.0: Adding to iommu group 31
[    0.487793] pci 0000:3e:05.1: Adding to iommu group 31
[    0.487816] pci 0000:3e:05.2: Adding to iommu group 31
[    0.487838] pci 0000:3e:05.3: Adding to iommu group 31
[    0.487896] pci 0000:3e:06.0: Adding to iommu group 32
[    0.487922] pci 0000:3e:06.1: Adding to iommu group 32
[    0.487946] pci 0000:3e:06.2: Adding to iommu group 32
[    0.487969] pci 0000:3e:06.3: Adding to iommu group 32
[    0.488088] DMAR: Intel(R) Virtualization Technology for Directed I/O
[    0.520152] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 driver by Joerg Roedel <jroedel@suse.de>
[    0.520153] AMD-Vi: AMD IOMMUv2 functionality not available on this system
[    1.253336]     intel_iommu=on
[   64.058649] vfio_iommu_type1_attach_group: No interrupt remapping support.  Use the module param "allow_unsafe_interrupts" to enable VFIO IOMMU support on this platform
```

I used the script from the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Ensuring_that_the_groups_are_valid) to ensure my groups:

```sh
...
IOMMU Group 16:
     03:00.0 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Netork Connection [8086:150e] (rev 01)
IOMMU Group 17:
     03:00.1 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Netork Connection [8086:150e] (rev 01)
IOMMU Group 18:
     03:00.2 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Netork Connection [8086:150e] (rev 01)
IOMMU Group 19:
     03:00.3 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82580 Gigabit Netork Connection [8086:150e] (rev 01)
...
```

And I verify my vfio groups

```sh
ls /dev/vfio
```

```sh
16 17 18 19 vfio
```

And I launch my VM

```sh
qemu-system-x86_y4 \
   -m 8G \
   -enable-kvm \
   -cpu host \
   -smp 2 \
   -net none \
   -device vfio-pci,host=03:00.0,id=net0 \
   -vga virtio -display gtk,gl=on \
   -drive format=qcow2,file=disk.cow,index=0,if=virtio \
   -drive if=pflash,format=raw,readonly=on,file=/usr/share/edk2-ovmf/x64/OVMF_CODE.fd \
   -drive if=pflash,format=raw,file=uefi_vars.fd
```

resulting in the following error:

```sh
qemu-system-x86_64: -device vfio-pci,host=03:00.0,id=net0: vfio 0000:03:00.0: failed to setup container for group 16: Failed to set iommu for container: Operation not permitted
```

I am not sure what to do next.  Any thoughts?